# How to add edge between two vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

How do I add edge and one vertex between two vertices in Blender 2.8?   I put a red dot where I'd like to have the new vertex:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make an edge between two vertices press <kbd>F</kbd>. If the vertices are on opposite sides of a face you can instead use <kbd>J</kbd> (for join).

To add a vertex, select the edge. Use Subdivide from the Edge menu.

To slide the vertex along the edge double press <kbd>G</kbd>.