# How to add an edge between two vertices

Tags: mesh

[image: seperate object]How can I add an edge between two vertex from different objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add edge between two vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167913/how-to-add-edge-between-two-vertices)

Comment: @brockmann Actually it's not directly a duplicate... he wants to connect two objects... maybe the title should be edited to clarify this?

Comment: Yeah, if you have the time please suggest an edit @GordonBrinkmann

Comment: another famous q&a: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one @GordonBrinkmann

Answer (score 2):

If your meshes are different objects you can't join the vertices. You'd have highlight the different objects in object mode and combine them into one object comprising of two separate meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

From here you can just select the two vertices and join them with <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: I've edited your answer to the correct shortcut.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann apologies, yes that was a silly mistake on my behalf

Comment: No problem, at first I even thought to remember it incorrectly...